# Have to add empty button to display call-out button in basic card

Tags: actions-on-google

When I create a basic card with call-out button (`url=tel:+…`) I have to add additional empty button, otherwise it won’t be displayed on the phone.

But if I add this empty button, the console emulator will display an extra empty one.

```
"buttons": [
  {
    "title": "1-855-xxx-xxxx",
    "openUrlAction": {
      "url": "tel:+1855xxxxxxx",
      "urlTypeHint": 0
    }
  },
  {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your question. Actions on Google platform does not support tel protocol in the "openUrlAction"'s url. The only valid protocols are http and https.